# Laptop emits pop sound and turns off

Tags: laptop, crash, battery, lenovo-laptop

Today I was watching movie without power charger plugged on and suddenly something inside laptop emitted pop sound (like someone popped bubble).

Then I collected some facts:

1. Laptop was not turning on when I was pressing power button without charger connected.
2. I plugged charger pressed power button and it turned on.
3. I unplugged charger after 2-3 seconds, While it was booting (on boot loader screen) after 2 seconds it made pop sound again from the bottom of right side and turned.
4. I booted OS after charging for 1 minute and plugged off charger and while on windows boot screen display tilted to save power (I did not know Windows 10 had such display driver feature while it is still loading),
5. I plugged charger back and display was brightened up to normal state.
6. Windows wrote that battery was charging.
7. When it turned of it was kind of on 20% charged. Usually windows shuts down after it reaches 7%.
8. When it happened first time the place where hit comes out from laptop was warmer than usually while watching movie without charger plugged.

Did someone had similar experience ? I think that it is related to battery. But I did not like that pop sound which might be coming from battery it feels like short circuit is happening inside while working with battery on low charge.

After this I went on youtube and watched laptop batteries exploding doe to overcharge or overdischarge and felt a bit afraid.

Comment: Blown capacitor would be my guess.

Comment: If you take the battery out, does the laptop work normally? The popping sound is probably something blowing out, a capacitor or some component... if you are lucky it is in the battery's circuitry, if it's inside the laptop on the mainboard, well, lets just say it might be time to start looking for a new laptop. :/

Comment: I will now play dota and wait until it charges fully and than I ll try to discharge it without being connected to charger and then I ll post update : P

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't sound like your connection is wonky, and that's good. Your best bet might be to just bite the bullet, buy a new battery (you can get them relatively cheap off of EBAY, just remember to refine to Lowest Price Lowest Shipping) and give it a try.

That said, it is *alarmingly* easy to overcharge a laptop battery. EBGreen could very well be correct, but it could also be several things, and most of them point to getting a new battery.

Comment: As I watched some videos on youtube I hope that if overcharge occurs battery will begin to expend in size and I will notice it before explosion takes place but they said that buttery will also explode while being discharged under some critical level. By my opinion it might happen if battery hardware will fail to pass certain charge level data to driver which makes os to shut down before reaching under 7% of battery power.